# Negative Dimension caused with input shape

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I am having an error with input size in my xception model.  The error is `ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 2 for 'conv2d_12/Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,7,2,728], [3,3,728,728].`  If you want everything the the program prints, please tell me.  Also, my model is at https://mystb.in/rebegituya.py.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the error was due to the number of layers in my neural net.  It works with that many layers with padding, but I just used a basic convnet for now.  I also used categorical_crossentropy for loss as sparse_categorical_crossentropy gives an error.